# Make a variable dynamic enough alter value based on month

Tags: sql-server, variables, dynamic

Is there any way to have a variable inside a variable loop through 12 numbers every time called? I may just be malnourished in SQL loop logic. Here is the variable I have, as of now I can only get it to hold a static number.

```
SET @startEnr = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
     FROM Enrollment
     WHERE MONTH(startDate) = 09
     AND active = 1
     AND endYear = 2020
```

The value 09 needs to hold 12 values as if @x = 1...12. I've attempted looping this however an error returns stating that the variable can't hold more than one value. Would I need a function?

Comment: Its not at all clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: You don't *call* a variable, you assign it a value or you read that value. Please explain why you would need what you describe.

Comment: Looping should be avoided at all costs. You definitely do **NOT** want a loop here. But since you are trying to evaluate 12 values which are months I have to ask what the point is of checking the month in the first place. There are exactly 0 months that are not between 1 and 12. You need to explain what you are really trying to accomplish here so others understand how to help you.

Comment: Im attempting to count the total enrollment data for every month. And i want to hold all those totals in a variable as if it was an array. Maybe ive missed something but all i know is that the only thing that will remotely do that is a a temp table itself. Thanks for the attention btw.

Comment: @JaySway The only real "array" in tsql is a table. This sounds like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) so it would be better to approach this from the perspective of your goal and not this particular implementation path (which likely will now work). So - what do you intend to do with the many monthly total enrollment values that you want to calculate?

Comment: @smor im trying to generate a spread sheet that will compare and contrast class enrollment percentages for the past months and few years. What might be the best approach to that in your oppinion? Im thinking of bagging the whole variable approach and going with temp tables. Its a tough report to pull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commenters have pointed out, the only real array in SQL is a table.  I think what you're looking for is something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #mthEnroll (mth int, cnt int)

INSERT INTO #mthEnroll (mth, cnt)
SELECT MONTH(startdate), COUNT(*) 
     FROM Enrollment
     WHEREactive = 1
     AND endYear = 2020
    GROUP BY MONTH(startdate)

DROP TABLE #mthEnroll
```

You may have to do some tinkering if you have the possibility of months with no entries (e.g., 0 students enrolled in July would NOT have a row), but if it's necessary to get 0's, there are other ways.

Comment: This is very helpful. I've just been approaching the problem as if I was using a different language. Thanks all of you so much.